# Can't rename folders in Window 7/32bit after anti-virus change

Tags: windows-7

I recently started having the common, as I realized, problem of not being able to rename folders in Windows 7 (32 bit).

I don't understand why it happened after almost a year of ideal use of Windows 7.

I haven't removed the libraries nor can I think of anything else that could potentially cause this, at least as far as I know.

The only thing I did recently was to change my anti-virus program from the freeware version of Avira to the freeware anti-virus Microsoft Security Essentials.

Any idea on what the problem is and how to fix this?

Comment: do you get any error while rename?

Comment: "Can't rename folder"? Why? What happens if you right-click the folder, choose "Rename", type a new name, then press Enter?

Answer (score 4):

Seems a Microsoft Update (KB980408) caused this issue on some systems.

```
“Deleting the following registry keys, and rebooting, has solved the problem for me:”

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{2112AB0A-C86A-4ffe-A368-0DE96E47012E}]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{491E922F-5643-4af4-A7EB-4E7A138D8174}]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{7b0db17d-9cd2-4a93-9733-46cc89022e7c}]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{A302545D-DEFF-464b-ABE8-61C8648D939B}]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{A990AE9F-A03B-4e80-94BC-9912D7504104}]
```

[Source of Information](http://www.overclock.net/windows/721973-msupdate-kb980408-warning-all-win7-x64-2.html#post9211430)

Comment: +1: Fixed it for me - had been suffering this for weeks! :)

Comment: Dude I would give you a nobel prize for this one! This should be marked as correct answer ! Only solution i found that actually works! Thanx

Answer (score 0):

You can try renaming using Command Prompt.

Comment: I get the error:

Comment: Item not found - but when i click try again it works

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [File Unlocker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Unlocker.shtml) to do it.   I recommend version 1.8.7 (which had no spyware/toolbar payload with it)  but version 1.9.1  might be safe to use.